# How can I select in table B depending on the activities took place in table A in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a form but It has a dropdown  which I populate dynamically From Table B , that part is fine.
Before data get populated in the drop down I have to check in the table where am going to post  data (Table A) to see if there is a record for the user (userid) who is going to post and the data(data ID ) which is going to be posted,  for the current date. If there is data for a different date I should proceed or if there is no data then still I have to proceed and populate the drop-down .

Table A  I where I post  fbgroupsid  , userid , userid, dateposted , dropdowndata , dataID
Table B  I select        fbgroupsid , personid  , dateposted , dropdowndata  ,fbgroupsid.

I tried the below code but I did not get the right results. any help will be appreciated .

```
SELECT 
TABLEb.fbgroupsid, 
TABLEb.name, 
TABLEb.fbgroupsid,
TABLEa.posteddate,
TABLEa.personid
FROM 
TABLEb
INNER JOIN TABLEa
ON 
TABLEb.fbgroupsid = TABLEa.fbgroupsid 

WHERE TABLEa.posteddate != CURDATE();
```

Comment: You have TABLEb.fbgroupsid twice in your select list.  Is the second one supposed to be TABLEa.fbgroupsid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *left* join on table a on the id and the date being the current date and then get everything where the tableA fbgroupsid is null

```
set @personId = 1;
SELECT 
TABLEb.fbgroupsid, 
TABLEb.name
FROM 
TABLEb
left JOIN TABLEa
ON 
TABLEb.fbgroupsid = TABLEa.fbgroupsid 
and DATE(TABLEa.posteddate) = CURDATE() 
and TableA.PersonId = @personId
where tablea.fbgroupsid is null;
```

Here is an [example in sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86f3fb/5/1). What is different either in the schema or the results from what you have or want?

Comment: everyone just loves a "where's waldo" style find the difference puzzle

Comment: @spencer7593 How's that?

Comment: it is not working in the perfect way , id should not be null the only thing is id must be not only having a record there under current date .

Comment: Post some example data and the results you want for it

Comment: @Kevin I sure I did not explain well but now I updated the question part I guess this time I explained well

Comment: @Humphrey I'm sorry, your updated explanation really isn't any clearer. In plain English, without worrying about code, what is this form/drop down supposed to do?  For example, "The drop down should list all users who are members of a group that haven't posted today" or "The form should have all the posts for a group for today"

Comment: @Kevin the drop down should have groups from the groupstable so we select one then we post on in it , then we save that info in another table with the ID of a member who posted , groupId and date. so next time if we want to  post , it should check if that member posted in that group in current date , if yes then that group don't appear in the dropdown .

Comment: @Humphrey I updated my answer. Does that work for you?

Comment: @Kevin no it does not , the drop down still brings all groups even if i post in one or two

Comment: @Humphrey that really doesn't make any sense.  You can see in the sqlfiddle that it's not returning groups that a user has posted in.  Maybe the problem isn't the sql query but a code issue.  Are you refreshing the list after each post?

Comment: @Humphrey What type of field is posteddate?

Comment: @Kevin  Am so happy you answer is the correct asnwer and you asking me about the date simplified things . This is what I wanted to ad it to your code . DATE(fbpost_info.posteddate) = CURDATE()

Comment: @Humphrey AHA! you (and I) are comparing a TIMESTAMP to a DATE.  That's going to fail unless they just happened to post at *exactly* at midnight

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210448/discussion-between-humphrey-and-kevin).